# ruby-readability: extra div added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is also reported at https://github.com/cantino/ruby-readability/issues/66

I'm using `ruby-readability`, https://github.com/cantino/ruby-readability

The problem is that it will return extra `div` for content.

For example:

```
content = "Remind's classroom communication app is used in more than half of all US public schools. It's be
  cause its co-founder Brett Kopf and team are unabashedly obsessed with their users. Here's how they
build remarkable relationships with customers. <br /><br />\n<a href=\"http://firstround.com/review/
your-users-deserve-better-an-inside-look-at-reminds-customer-obsession/?utm_medium=rss&amp;utm_sourc
e=frr_feed&amp;utm_campaign=home_stream&amp;utm_content=read_more\">Continue reading at First Round
Review &raquo;</a>"
  content =  Readability::Document.new(content, :tags => %w[div p a], :attributes => %w[src href], :remove_empty_nodes => true).content
```

will return

```
=> "<div><div><p>Remind's classroom communication app is used in more than half of all US public sch
ools. It's be\n  cause its co-founder Brett Kopf and team are unabashedly obsessed with their users.
 Here's how they\nbuild remarkable relationships with customers. </p><p><a href=\"http://firstround.
com/review/&#10;your-users-deserve-better-an-inside-look-at-reminds-customer-obsession/?utm_medium=r
ss&amp;utm_sourc&#10;e=frr_feed&amp;utm_campaign=home_stream&amp;utm_content=read_more\">Continue re
ading at First Round\nReview »</a></p></div></div>"
```

I'm wondering, what is the problem, and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you  remove the `div` in the constructor? In other words: `Readability::Document.new(content, :tags => %w[p a], :attributes => %w[src href], :remove_empty_nodes => true)`.

Comment: @AnthonyE, just tried that. It will not have the `div`, but it also filtered out the `a`, that's really unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to stem from the fact that your input html has only a single paragraph. If I understand it correctly, the `ruby-readibility` gem seems to search for articles (typically denoted by a `<div>` tag) in the input html **that consist of one or more paragraphs** (`<p>` elements). It searches through all these paragraphs, calculates their relevance and tries to determine the main article on the page.

The important fact is that it determines the "article" as the **parent node** of the paragraphs with the highest score (see [here](https://github.com/cantino/ruby-readability/blob/master/lib/readability.rb#L321)).

Now, the two `<div>` tags are added in the [`get_article` method](https://github.com/cantino/ruby-readability/blob/master/lib/readability.rb#L258). The method first *always* wraps the found article with a `<div>` ([here](https://github.com/cantino/ruby-readability/blob/master/lib/readability.rb#L263)). Then, it copies all children tags of the found article and if the article itself is a different tag than `<p>` or `<div>`, it changes the tag to `<div>` ([here](https://github.com/cantino/ruby-readability/blob/master/lib/readability.rb#L283)). Because your article node, i.e. the parent node of the single paragraph in your input html, is the `<body>` tag, it is changed to a `<div>` tag, effectively resulting in two `<div>`s in the output.

The most correct way to fix this would probably be a special handling of the case when an article is actually the body of the page in the `get_article` method. Or, you might just ignore the double `<div>`s in your case.